# Bricked my PC trying to setup secure-boot

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, bios, secure-boot

I have dualboot (windows & arch), i was trying to setup secure boot in arch using `sbctl`. But i think i ran the wrong command and bricked my keys. Now when i startup computer, it get stuck in blank screen (keyboard, mouse and fans are enabled). I have tried clear cmos.
I suspect that ocurred that is describes here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#Using_your_own_keys.

Obs: my cpu is i310100f (dont have integrated graphics), motherboard is a GigaByte H410M H v3 with nvidia gtx1650

Comment: Why would this be a good idea? If you want to run Windows, you are forced to use secure boot - but Linux can run using the "shim" to effectively bypass secure boot. Note that "secure boot" doesn't really secure anything - except effectively lock you into Windows.

Comment: @JeremyBoden *If you want to run Windows, you are forced to use secure boot* .. I disagree (or perhaps misunderstand this statement) - I have 3 x Windows 11 PC's, none of them use secure boot.

Comment: Can you boot to installer?

Comment: It is a mistake to think the Secure Boot actually secures anything apart locking you to Windows only. Never ever enabled it myself.

Comment: unfortunately some programs need this active, I thought it would be a simple process

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your motherboard and UEFI firmware implementation, clearing the CMOS may or may not reset the Secure Boot keys. Can you get into BIOS settings? There might be an option to reset the Secure Boot keys to factory defaults.

If you cannot get into BIOS settings, you should check the motherboard/system documentation: if the motherboard has a way to recover from a failed BIOS update, it might also reset the Secure Boot keys when used.

Another thing to try is to find out the key you'd normally press during boot to access the BIOS settings, then hold it down (or keep tapping it) blindly while powering on the system.

After clearing the CMOS, the system might have switched to using the iGPU as the primary display controller, so try moving the display cable from the NVidia card to the iGPU's display connector and see if anything is displayed there.

Comment: No, when i startup it only show a blank screen

Comment: My processor doesn't have an integrated video, is it still possible somehow?

Comment: If your processor does not have integrated video, then the switching should not be an issue to you.